# How to interpret division of Korean names when citing articles?

Tags: publications, citations, etiquette, personal-name, asia

I'm preparing bibliography using Microsoft Word's bibliography creator, which look like this:

[image]

I would like to insert Korean author Won-Hwa Park. Where to put his names in the "Add name" section? What is his first, last and middle name? What are rules that govern citing Korean authors?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I just want to remark that a lot of language don't have middle name. It seems to be an English-speaking tradition...

Comment: The only 'real' purpose to getting this right is to be sure that your citation could lead somebody to the correct paper.  These days that will often mean a search in a database. I have gone in to Web of Science to see which permutations of names will lead to the paper popping up (and avoid the ones that don't). Perhaps brute force, but if you comply with a Korean convention that does not lead a reader to the article, well, that isn't very useful to the reader.

Comment: The "last" name (i.e. the family name) is Park. First name Won Hwa (or Wonhwa/Won-Hwa/Won-hwa). No middle name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three general naming conventions you need to familiarize yourself with for proper citation in a modern context: European, Middle Eastern and East Asian.

## European

(Primary Given Name) (Optional Secondary etc. Given Name[s]) (Family Name)

*(John) (Mephistophiles) (Smith)*

## East Asian

(Family Name) (Given Name)

*(Huang) (Jieshi)*

or

*(Park) (Hwa-won)*

In this case the Family name is usually 1 Chinese character, and the given name is 2 characters (even if the characters are no longer used as in Korea and Viet-nam). In Chinese, Korean, and Viet-namese that *usually* means one syllable per character, but in Japanese it varies wildly.

Many times the romanization of the East Asian names will join the given name with a hype (Won-Hwa) or have them as a single, unbroken word. However, sometimes they are broken apart, in two words, but they are still **one name**. When in doubt, Google the name you suspect to be the family name. If it is the family name, there will be lots and lots of people with that name. (Park is the most common name in Korea).

## Middle Eastern

(Given Name) (Father's Given Name) (Grandfather's Given Name) (Tribal or Locational Name)

Sometimes the Fathers and Grandfathers given name is preceded by an article like 'bin' (Arabic), 'ben' (Hebrew), 'ibn' (Classical Arabic), or substituted for 'bint' or other female forms before the father's name if a woman. The locational name will almost always be preceded by the article, 'al'. The articles may be separated from the names by a hyphen or not, but when written should be included, but not usually when spoken unless in *very* formal circumstances.

*(Mahmoud) bin (Hamid) bin (Abdul-Qadr) (al-Hashemi)*

In a citation manager it should be entered as follow:

[image: Table of Citation Manager Name Entries]

Following this table your entry should be:
Last Name = "Park", First Name = "Won-Hwa", Middle Name = ""